# Use regular expression to look for "%"

Tags: java, regex

I'm programming in Java and I want to use regex to look for any data with a percent sign, e.g. 10%, 20%,30%,etc. I've tried `a.matches("%")`but that only returns true if the string matches exactly the percent sign. What should be the correct regular expression to use? Thanks

Comment: that gave me an error but a.matches("%*") works! thanks!

Comment: [This guide](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) appears to be better than my suggestion. In java the wildcard is actually `.` apparently (I know little of Java).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just looking for a '%', then `String.indexOf('%')` would probably be faster and simpler than any regular-expression-based solution.

Considering regular expressions, the `matches()` function attempts to match the entire string to the pattern, as you've discovered. `Matcher.find()` will look for substrings within the string that match the pattern, for example:

```
Pattern pp = Pattern.compile("%");
Matcher mm = pp.matcher(someString);
if (mm.find()) {
    // someString contains a '%'
    ...
}
```